# Erro de ambiguidade Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

[image: Erro de ambiguidade]

com esse controller:

```
  public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ImagemId,Image,ImagemTipo")]Imagem imagem,List <HttpPostedFileBase> upload)
    {

        if(upload != null && upload.Count> 0) {


            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in upload)
            {
                var arqImagem = new Imagem
                {
                    ImagemTipo = file.ContentType
                };
                using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                {
                    arqImagem.Image = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                }
                imagem.Image = arqImagem.Image;
                imagem.ImagemTipo = arqImagem.ImagemTipo;

                db.Imagems.Add(imagem);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }


        return View(imagem);
    }
```

Obtive esse erro: que eu não consigui resolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tem 2 `ActionResult` com o mesmo nome não? Se sim, os argumentos não estão sendo suficientes para diferenciar os 2.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolve. Como procedo? como fechar a pergunta?

Comment: @RafaelG, aqui você só precisa aceitar a resposta que achar melhor, não é necessário fechar. Pode ainda dar um UP Vote para quem te ajudou. :)